# How to get the id or details of the item right clicked from context menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a table populated using AngularJS. On the right click of the link button in the table, I want to display a specific context menu(which I created using Jquery). It was fine. I can see the Context Menu on right click. However, If I click on any options in the Context Menu like "Delete" I want to get the Id of the item clicked. It should be passed as a parameter so that I can handle that function. I am always getting Id as undefined.

Please assist me on how to get the Id of the item right clicked in the Context Menu?

```js
//Context Menu Functions
var $contextMenu = $("#contextMenu");

$("body").on("contextmenu", "table tbody button", function(e) {
  $contextMenu.css({
    display: "block",
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });
  return false;
});

$contextMenu.on("click", "a", function() {
  $contextMenu.hide();
});

$("html").click(function() {
  $contextMenu.hide();
});

$scope.nodes = [{
    "id": 228,
    "name": "Folder 1",
    "descr": "",
    "path": "227/",
    "mm": true
  },
  {
    "id": 229,
    "name": "Folder 2",
    "descr": "",
    "path": "227/",
    "mm": true
  }
];

//Calling Delete Function on Context Menu
$scope.deleteFolder = function(detailid) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(detailid));
  //this returns me Undefined. If I had sent detail instead of detail.id - its returning me full json. 
};
```

```css
#contextMenu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}

.contextmenustyle {
  display: block;
  position: static;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="foldertable">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Members</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="projtable">
    <tr ng-repeat="detail in nodes" ng-mouseover="showShare()">
      <td><button id="namesdetails" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="openFolder(detail.id, detail.name)" style="text-decoration: none !important">
 <span class="fa fa-folder" style="font-size: larger"></span> 
{{detail.name}}</button></td>
      <td> -- </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- context menu -->
<div id="contextMenu" class="dropdown clearfix">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu contextmenustyle" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit/Rename</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" ng-click="deleteFolder(detail.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Pass event in context menu as well: $contextMenu.on("click", "a", function(e) {})

Comment: I tried. Its returning me all junk other than Id. {"originalEvent":{"isTrusted":true},"type":"contextmenu","target":{"jQuery311069559266060260442":{"$binding":["detail.name"]},"jQuery311069559266060260441":{"events":{"click":[{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":127,"namespace":""}]}}},"currentTarget":{"jQuery311069559266060260442":{"$binding":["detail.name"]},"jQuery311069559266060260441":{"events":{"click":[{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":127,"namespace":""}]}}...................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an easy solution we could make a context menu for every `detail` `object`.

> Your main problem was that the context menu div is outside of your
>   `ng-repeat` loop so you can't get `detail.id` there.

I have put it inside your loop and changed the context menu id to class and everything work as your code. Just ignore the other angular specific code like ng-controller, ng-app those are only for this demo work. As you can see when i showing the context menu this way

```
$(this).parent().find('.contextMenu').css({
  display: "block",
  left: e.pageX,
  top: e.pageY
});
```

I also have made a [Working jsBin](https://jsbin.com/deqitosabe/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $("body").on("contextmenu", "table tbody button", function(e) {
    $(".contextMenu").hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.contextMenu').css({
      display: "block",
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
    return false;
  });
  $(".contextMenu").on("click", "a", function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $("html").click(function() {
    $(".contextMenu").hide();
  });
  $scope.nodes = [{
      "id": 228,
      "name": "Folder 1",
      "descr": "",
      "path": "227/",
      "mm": true
    },
    {
      "id": 229,
      "name": "Folder 2",
      "descr": "",
      "path": "227/",
      "mm": true
    }
  ];
  $scope.deleteFolder = function(detailid) {
    console.log(detailid);
  };
});
```

```css
.contextMenu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}

.contextmenustyle {
  display: block;
  position: static;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="foldertable">
    <thead>
      <tr style="text-align: center">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Members</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="projtable">
      <tr ng-repeat="detail in nodes" ng-mouseover="showShare()">
        <td><button id="namesdetails" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="openFolder(detail.id, detail.name)" style="text-decoration: none !important"> <span class="fa fa-folder" style="font-size: larger"></span> {{detail.name}}</button>
          <div class="dropdown clearfix contextMenu">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu contextmenustyle" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit/Rename</a></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" ng-click="deleteFolder(detail.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td> -- </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include this `id` as data attribute to your button:

```
<button ng-click="openFolder(detail.id, detail.name)" data-id="{{detail.id}}">
```

So on triggering context menu event you will have your button as context and can read id from data attributes

```
$("body").on("contextmenu", "table tbody button", function(e) {
  console.log($(this).data('id'));
  return false;
});
```

Comment: On adding the attribute, the contextmenu is not working. Its not displaying the options also now.

Comment: Some errors inside? Use another attr name like `data-detaild-id`. Maybe plugin uses this attribute also. No  - just wrap this into jQuery. I've changed code

Comment: I am getting console.log(this.data('id')); -- undefined for this now

Comment: Is this fiddle close to your page? https://jsfiddle.net/vadimb/8pv0xywL/1/ 
Check console - it prints `123` from data attribute. Check you have correct `detailId` interpolated to this attributes

Comment: Nope. I am not yet handy with fiddle and neither attaching a good snippet here. Learning it. However the solution I have marked Yes works fine. Its becos my context menu is outside the div and some changes made in contextmenu definitions. It works fine. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Some change in bind function is require to get the clicked object.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
{{temp}}
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="foldertable">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Members</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="projtable">
    <tr ng-repeat="detail in nodes" ng-mouseover="showShare()">
      <td><button id="namesdetails" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="openFolder(detail.id, detail.name)" style="text-decoration: none !important">

 <span class="fa fa-folder" style="font-size: larger"></span> 
{{detail.name}}</button></td>
      <td> -- </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- context menu -->
<div id="contextMenu" class="dropdown clearfix">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu contextmenustyle" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" attr="edit" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit/Rename</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" attr="delete" ng-click="deleteFolder(detail.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Bind Click Function:

```
$contextMenu.on("click", "a", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.attributes.attr.value); //delete or edit
  $contextMenu.hide();
});
```

Passed event in the bind function. you can get the object of clicked  in the click function.

Comment: How can I get the Object of the Clicked in the click function? I used ur snipped $(e.currentTarget) and it returns {"0":{"jQuery311072329403858592321":{"events":{"click":[{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":102,"namespace":""},{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":103,"namespace":""}]}}},"length":1}